# Cloning a model in Factory Girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I want to use Factory Girl to generate a large collection of models, each of which only differ by one or two attributes.

Is there a way to have a factory accept an instance of a model? Ideally, I'd like

```
  before(:all) do
    data1 = create(:instance,
             :attribute_1 => 1,
             :attribute_2 => 2,
             :attribute_3 => "something",
             :attribute_4 => "something else",
             :attribute_5 => 5
             ...
    )

    data2 = create(:instance,
                  :attribute 2 => 15,
                  base: data1
    )
  end
```

data2 would be initialized as a clone of data1, and I could just specify the new attributes I wanted to overwrite.

I've tried using transient attributes but can't see a way to implement something like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :instance do
    ignore do
      base nil
    end
    attribute_1 { base.nil? ? argument.attribute_1 : base.attribute_1 + argument.attribute_1 }
    attribute_2 { base.nil? ? argument.attribute_2 : base.attribute_2 + argument.attribute_1 }
    ...
  end
end
```

Am I'm approaching this in entirely the wrong way?

Comment: Do you want to maintain the same associations on the model, while changing those few attributes?

Comment: In this case, I don't have any associations, and in the broader scheme of things, I can imagine cases for both preserving them and not. I haven't investigated Factory Girl's idioms for managing associations yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do it more simply by just defining the hash of attributes you want to use and then changing it slightly for the second call?

Something like:

```
data_attributes = {
         :attribute_1 => 1,
         :attribute_2 => 2,
         :attribute_3 => "something",
         :attribute_4 => "something else",
         :attribute_5 => 5
         ...
}
data1 = create(:instance, data_attributes)

data2 = create(:instance, data_attributes.merge(:attribute_2 => 1))
```

I appreciate that that doesn't exactly answer your question but it might solve your problem.

Comment: That's not bad at all. It actually does answer my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to generate attributes that differ, have you looked at [sequences](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage)?

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  sequence :foo { |n| "#{n}" }

  factory :data { foo }
end
```

In your spec:

```
data1 = FactoryGirl.create(:data)
data1.foo
  => "1"

data2 = FactoryGirl.create(:data) #It makes new, unique attributes for you
data2.foo
  => "2"
```

Comment: Sequences are an option for some attributes. For others, I like to assign dummy data that bears a little closer semblance to actual business data. Not for accuracy so much as just to keep the test cases straight in my head.

Comment: You can mix sequences and other attributes in your FactoryGirl definition. And you can make logic for sequences that makes them look more businessy.